# Button in a WPF ListItem

Tags: wpf, data-binding, button

I'm a bit new to WPF. I am working on a list UI where each item in the list will have a set of corresponding buttons to operate on that particular data item.

Coming from a web background, I normally would have bound the value into a hidden element in that particular list item or something. However, I just need to find the corresponding technique in this WPF world :-)

Comment: Not quite yet ... I've been trying to bind a routed command to the button, but am not having much luck getting the command to execute

Comment: Hey, please report the progress or ask if you need any help.

Comment: I did figure it out, thank you very much for your initial guidance. Ultimately, the problems I was having was related to having to manually declare the namespace in the XAML, and then using the namespace when binding the command to ui elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common technique is to use templates. Please consider using my example of a templated ListItem (for example ListBoxItem):

```
   <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Command="{Binding Path=YourCommand}" Content="Dynamic Button 1" />
                    <Button Command="{Binding Path=YourSecondCommand}" Content="Dynamic Button 2" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Please feel free to ask if you have any questions/ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see ... ok, so how would I a) define YourCommand so that the binding above routes it correctly, and b) in that command, how do I reference the list item's data object so that I can operate on it?

Comment: You will have to prepare appropriate DataContext for your View. This sounds scary at the beginning, but very soon you will find that extremely easy. Please take a look on this great article covering  bound commands (using MVVM design pattern) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx Author used TreeView, but you can use Listbox as well with no hierarchical data templates. It seems to be complicated at first glance, but to use full potential of WPF you'll have to get familiar with bindings. Please give me a shout if you nedd help!